# Large difference between GAM model predictions and mean values

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, gam

I have 3 predictor variables: Year (2010-2019), Management (Tabu/Open) and Fishing method (Spear, Line, Trolling or Net). I have fit GAMs to three response variables: Effort (Hours), Catch (Weight, kg) and Efficiency (Catch per Unit Effort, CPUE). For all three models Year has been fit as a Gam by Management, with Management and Method also included as fixed effects (This combination had the lowest AIC and is the most relevant for our question). All three response variables were skewed and needed to be LogX+1 transformed. Following the transformation both Weight and CPUE were still skewed, although the plots of residual histogram and residuals vs. fitted values were acceptable, as was a test for overdispersion.

There is a lot of variability in the data, so the models only explain between 5-10% of the deviance.

Using visreg I have plotted the model with the raw data overlaid. However given it's spread this is difficult to interpret. Instead I then plotted the mean/SE over the model using geom_pointrange.

- For the Hours figure the model fit the means and error for each year/Management type quite well.
- For the Weight figure the model is predicting well below the mean/SE for each year, and the slope for Management="Tabu open" isn't right.
- For CPUE the model shape is roughly correct, but it is much higher than the mean/SE pointranges.

Given it worked for Hours , I am guessing the problem is with the skewedness of the data for Weight and CPUE, even though the model validations were acceptable.

Why is there so little overlap between the model and the mean/SE data for Weight and CPUE but not for Hours?

Is there another better way to plot the model rather than overlaid with either 1. The raw data or 2. The means?

Code is as follows:

```
summary(reeffish)

      Year            Management       Method        Hours            Weight             CPUE        
 Min.   :2010   Always open:398   Line    :417   Min.   : 0.500   Min.   :  0.000   Min.   : 0.0000  
 1st Qu.:2011   Tabu open  :312   Net     : 49   1st Qu.: 3.000   1st Qu.:  1.196   1st Qu.: 0.2735  
 Median :2013                     Spear   :217   Median : 4.420   Median :  2.200   Median : 0.5092  
 Mean   :2013                     Trolling: 27   Mean   : 5.689   Mean   :  4.108   Mean   : 0.8665  
 3rd Qu.:2014                                    3rd Qu.: 6.567   3rd Qu.:  4.234   3rd Qu.: 0.9472  
 Max.   :2019                                    Max.   :67.330   Max.   :152.000   Max.   :14.7800
```

```
#Fit model
Hours.gam1 = gam(log(Hours+1) ~ s(Year, k=5,by=Management) + Management+Method, data= reeffish)
Weight.gam1 = gam(log(Weight+1) ~ s(Year, k=5,by=Management) + Management+Method, data= reeffish)
CPUE.gam1 = gam(log(CPUE+1) ~ s(Year, k=5,by=Management) + Management+Method,data= reeffish)
```

```
#Model Validation
#Hours
E3 <- resid(Hours.gam1); F3 <- fitted(Hours.gam1) # get the residuals and fitted values
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(5,4,3,3))  # this is setting up a multi-panel plot window
hist(E3, breaks=25,main="",xlab="Residuals")
plot(x=F3, y=E3, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Residuals")
abline(0,0)

#Weight
E3 <- resid(Weight.gam1); F3 <- fitted(Weight.gam1) # get the residuals and fitted values
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(5,4,3,3))  # this is setting up a multi-panel plot window
hist(E3, breaks=25,main="",xlab="Residuals")
plot(x=F3, y=E3, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Residuals")
abline(0,0)

#CPUE
E3 <- resid(CPUE.gam1); F3 <- fitted(CPUE.gam1) # get the residuals and fitted values
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(5,4,3,3))  # this is setting up a multi-panel plot window
hist(E3, breaks=25,main="",xlab="Residuals")
plot(x=F3, y=E3, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Residuals")
abline(0,0)
```

[Residual plots of Hours, Weight and CPUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhRCo.jpg)

```
#Model Output
summary(Hours.gam1)
summary(Weight.gam1)
summary(CPUE.gam1)
```

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
log(Hours + 1) ~ s(Year, k = 5, by = Management) + Management + 
    Method

Parametric coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          1.637127   0.030477  53.717  < 2e-16 ***
ManagementTabu open  0.123398   0.051120   2.414 0.016040 *  
MethodNet            0.284026   0.080653   3.522 0.000457 ***
MethodSpear          0.001778   0.047798   0.037 0.970341    
MethodTrolling      -0.224008   0.103047  -2.174 0.030054 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(Year):ManagementAlways open 1.000  1.000 2.660  0.1033  
s(Year):ManagementTabu open   1.908  2.262 3.463  0.0219 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.043   Deviance explained = 5.24%
GCV = 0.27033  Scale est. = 0.2673    n = 704

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
log(Weight + 1) ~ s(Year, k = 5, by = Management) + Management + 
    Method

Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          1.14805    0.03944  29.107  < 2e-16 ***
ManagementTabu open -0.06480    0.06473  -1.001    0.317    
MethodNet            0.57534    0.10475   5.493 5.56e-08 ***
MethodSpear          0.31332    0.06173   5.076 4.96e-07 ***
MethodTrolling      -0.09969    0.13294  -0.750    0.454    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df     F p-value
s(Year):ManagementAlways open 1.742  2.021 1.809   0.161
s(Year):ManagementTabu open   1.770  2.118 0.758   0.406

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0714   Deviance explained = 8.14%
GCV = 0.44714  Scale est. = 0.44173   n = 704

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
log(CPUE + 1) ~ s(Year, k = 5, by = Management) + Management + 
    Method

Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.46682    0.02180  21.418  < 2e-16 ***
ManagementTabu open -0.09232    0.03157  -2.924  0.00357 ** 
MethodNet            0.25574    0.05789   4.418 1.16e-05 ***
MethodSpear          0.18187    0.03409   5.335 1.29e-07 ***
MethodTrolling       0.04806    0.07345   0.654  0.51306    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                               edf Ref.df     F p-value
s(Year):ManagementAlways open 1.82  2.092 1.813   0.154
s(Year):ManagementTabu open   1.00  1.000 0.922   0.337

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0725   Deviance explained = 8.15%
GCV = 0.13622  Scale est. = 0.1347    n = 704
```

```
#Plot model
Hours.visreg=visreg(Hours.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=FALSE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
Weight.visreg=visreg(Weight.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=FALSE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
CPUE.visreg=visreg(CPUE.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=FALSE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
```

[Model plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTuM.jpg)

```
visreg(Hours.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=TRUE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
visreg(Weight.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=TRUE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
visreg(CPUE.gam1,"Year", by="Management" , partial=TRUE, overlay=TRUE, trans=exp)
```

[Model plots with Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uLql.jpg)

```
#Plot model with Means overlaid, calculated outside of R
Means.alldata<- read.csv('reeffishMeans.csv', header= T, strip.white= T)
Means.alldata=Means.alldata%>% mutate(Year=as.integer(Year))

#Hours figure
Hours.reeffish.gam= ggplot(data=Means.alldata, aes(x=Year, y=Hours, fill=factor(Management), color=factor(Management)))+
  geom_ribbon(data= Hours.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year, ymin=visregLwr, ymax=visregUpr), alpha=0.5, linetype=1, size=0.2, colour=NA) +
  geom_line(data=Hours.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year,y=visregFit, group=Management, color=Management), lwd=1) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin= Hours-HoursSE, ymax= Hours+HoursSE), width=.5, size=0.5, position=position_dodge(.05))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('deepskyblue4', 'coral2'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('deepskyblue3', 'coral1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(name=expression('Fishing Effort (Hours)'), limits=c(2,8), breaks=c(2,4,6,8)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name=expression('Year'), limits=c(2009,2020), breaks=c(2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y= element_text(size=14), axis.text.y= element_text(size=12), axis.text.x= element_text(size=12), axis.title.x= element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14))

#Weight figure
Weight.reeffish.gam= ggplot(data=Means.alldata, aes(x=Year, y=Weight, fill=factor(Management), color=factor(Management)))+
  geom_ribbon(data= Weight.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year, ymin=visregLwr, ymax=visregUpr), alpha=0.5, linetype=1, size=0.2, colour=NA) +
  geom_line(data=Weight.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year,y=visregFit, group=Management, color=Management), lwd=1) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin= Weight-WeightSE, ymax= Weight+WeightSE), width=.5, size=0.5, position=position_dodge(.05))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('deepskyblue4', 'coral2'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('deepskyblue3', 'coral1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(name=expression('Catch (Kg)'), limits=c(0,8), breaks=c(2,4,6,8)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name=expression('Year'), limits=c(2009,2020), breaks=c(2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y= element_text(size=14), axis.text.y= element_text(size=12), axis.text.x= element_text(size=12), axis.title.x= element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14))

#CPUE figure
CPUE.reeffish.gam= ggplot(data=Means.alldata, aes(x=Year, y=CPUE, fill=factor(Management), color=factor(Management)))+
  geom_ribbon(data= CPUE.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year, ymin=visregLwr, ymax=visregUpr), alpha=0.5, linetype=1, size=0.2, colour=NA) +
  geom_line(data=CPUE.visreg$fit, aes(x=Year,y=visregFit, group=Management, color=Management), lwd=1) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin= CPUE-CPUESE, ymax= CPUE+CPUESE), width=.5, size=0.5, position=position_dodge(.05))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('deepskyblue4', 'coral2'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('deepskyblue3', 'coral1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(name=expression('CPUE'), limits=c(0,2), breaks=c(0,.5,1,1.5,2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name=expression('Year'), limits=c(2009,2020), breaks=c(2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y= element_text(size=14), axis.text.y= element_text(size=12), axis.text.x= element_text(size=12), axis.title.x= element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14))

Hours.reeffish.gam
Weight.reeffish.gam
CPUE.reeffish.gam
```

[Model plots with Means of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kq4C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have since found out the issue. Because data were log(x+1) transformed, but only back transformed by trans=exp, the model predictions are all out by one. This only showed up as a noticeable difference for CPUE because their units were much smaller.